# Training ARIMAX model with MLE (Kalman Update)

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, arima, autoregressive

I refer to this https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.fit.html where it states that the variables of an ARIMAX model is fit by MLE via Kalman Filter. I've used statsmodels on several occasion but I am trying to implement the ARIMAX function as an exercise so I fully understand what it's doing.

Given $\boldsymbol{y}_t = \boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}_t + \boldsymbol{B}_1\boldsymbol{y}_{t-1} + \boldsymbol{B}_2\boldsymbol{y}_{t-2}$ where $\boldsymbol{x}_t$ is the exogenous variables at time $t$ and the lag is $2$.

My question is how do I learn the weights $\boldsymbol{A}, \boldsymbol{B}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{B}_2$?

This is what I have done so far (implemented in Python). Suppose I have data in this form:
$\boldsymbol{y}_6=\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}_6 + \boldsymbol{B}_1\boldsymbol{y}_{5} + \boldsymbol{B}_2\boldsymbol{y}_{4}$
$\boldsymbol{y}_5=\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}_5 + \boldsymbol{B}_1\boldsymbol{y}_{4} + \boldsymbol{B}_2\boldsymbol{y}_{3}$
$\boldsymbol{y}_4=\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}_3 + \boldsymbol{B}_1\boldsymbol{y}_{4} + \boldsymbol{B}_2\boldsymbol{y}_{2}$ etc.

To predict the next timestep $\boldsymbol{y}_7$ I need to first learn the weights. My steps are:
1. Optimize for weight $\boldsymbol{A}$ using 
$\boldsymbol{y}_6=\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}_6, \boldsymbol{y}_5=\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}_5, \boldsymbol{y}_4=\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}_3$.
2. Suppose learnt $\boldsymbol{A}$ is $\boldsymbol{A}'$, compute $\boldsymbol{y}'_6=\boldsymbol{A}'\boldsymbol{x}_6, \boldsymbol{y}'_5=\boldsymbol{A}'\boldsymbol{x}_5, \boldsymbol{y}'_4=\boldsymbol{A}'\boldsymbol{x}_3$.
3. Compute the residuals as $\boldsymbol{y}_t - \boldsymbol{y}'_t = \boldsymbol{B}_1\boldsymbol{y}_{t-1} + \boldsymbol{B}_2\boldsymbol{y}_{t-2}$ and optimize for $\boldsymbol{B}_1$ using the residuals.
4. Repeat for all other lags.
5. Once all weights $\boldsymbol{A}, \boldsymbol{B}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{B}_2$ are learnt, predict for $\boldsymbol{y}_7$ using $\boldsymbol{y}'_7=\boldsymbol{A}'\boldsymbol{x}_7 + \boldsymbol{B}'_1\boldsymbol{y}_{6} + \boldsymbol{B}'_2\boldsymbol{y}_{5}$

My observation from my implementation (walk-forward validation) is that while $\boldsymbol{y}_t$ is sensitive to any change in $\boldsymbol{x}_t$, multi-timestep-out-of-sample prediction is a flat line (when $\boldsymbol{x}_t$ is constant).

Upon inspection, $\boldsymbol{B}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{B}_2$ are nearly zero and this is perhaps due to the residuals having a mean of zero.

Would appreciate some feedback if I'm approaching this the correct way, or my understanding on the concept has been wrong all along. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What parameters did you use when you generated your test data?

Comment: @jbowman I generated the time-series vector using heat diffusion PDE and each vector is observations at some point in space. For example, $\boldsymbol{y}_t$ could have a dimension $3 \times 1$ and $\boldsymbol{x}_t$ could have a dimension  $2 \times 1$ and $\boldsymbol{A}$ is then $3 \times 2$.  In my case $\boldsymbol{A}$ is not known exactly, hence I'm trying to use ARIMAX to learn $\boldsymbol{A}, \boldsymbol{B}_1, \boldsymbol{B}_2$. Are you trying to imply that I should generate a test case with known parameters?

Comment: Yes, exactly.   After all, maybe the series actually have $B_1$ and $B_2$ matrices with small values.

Comment: @jbowman Thank you for the suggestion! Indeed, I checked that $\boldsymbol{B}_1, \boldsymbol{B}_2$ do have really small values. I suppose if $\boldsymbol{A}$ has been learnt exactly, then what is left in the residuals is just Gaussian noise that I added to my data.